# How to run a class from Jar which is not the Main-Class in its Manifest file

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have a JAR with 4 classes, each one has Main method. I want to be able to run each one of those as per the need. I am trying to run it from command-line on Linux box.

```
E.g. The name of my JAR is MyJar.jar
```

It has directory structure for the main classes as follows:

```
com/mycomp/myproj/dir1/MainClass1.class
com/mycomp/myproj/dir2/MainClass2.class
com/mycomp/myproj/dir3/MainClass3.class
com/mycomp/myproj/dir4/MainClass4.class
```

I know that I can specify one class as main in my Manifest file. But is there any way by which I can specify some argument on command line to run whichever class I wish to run?

I tried this:

```
jar cfe MyJar.jar com.mycomp.myproj.dir2.MainClass2 com/mycomp/myproj/dir2/MainClass2.class /home/myhome/datasource.properties /home/myhome/input.txt
```

And I got this error:

```
com/mycomp/myproj/dir2/MainClass2.class : no such file or directory
```

(In the above command, '/home/myhome/datasource.properties' and '/home/myhome/input.txt' are the command line arguments).

Comment: Just package them in different jars, using another jar to hold the dependencies?

Comment: Why not have single main class that calls the specific method(out of the 4) based on command line arguments?

Answer (score 275, accepted):

You can create your jar without Main-Class in its Manifest file. Then :

```
java -cp MyJar.jar com.mycomp.myproj.dir2.MainClass2 /home/myhome/datasource.properties /home/myhome/input.txt
```

Comment: According to the doc this won't work: "In order for this option to work, the manifest of the JAR file must contain a line of the form Main-Class: classname. "

Comment: "Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from MyJar.jar"

Comment: Thomas is right. you need replace "-jar" with "-cp". See my updated code

Comment: The answer provided by @chrisdew works without having to change the Jar file by modifying/removing the Main-Class attribute.

Answer (score 220):

You can execute *any* class which has a `public static void main` method from a JAR file, *even if the jar file has a `Main-Class` defined*.

Execute Main-Class:

```
java -jar MyJar.jar  // will execute the Main-Class
```

Execute another class with a `public static void main` method:

```
java -cp MyJar.jar com.mycomp.myproj.AnotherClassWithMainMethod
```

Note: the first uses `-jar`, the second uses `-cp`.

Comment: And if you want all jars in current directory on classpath too (eg. running Main class from lib directory) you can use `java -cp "./*" com.mycomp.myproj.AnotherClassWithMainMethod`
Note the double quotes around `./*` preventing unix machines from expanding it. Also note that `"./*.jar"` will not work.

Answer (score 40):

#### This answer is for Spring-boot users:

If your JAR was from a `Spring-boot` project and created using the command `mvn package spring-boot:repackage`, the above "-cp" method won't work. You will get:

> Error: Could not find or load main class your.alternative.class.path

even if you can see the class in the JAR by `jar tvf yours.jar`.

In this case, run your alternative class by the following command:

```
java -cp yours.jar -Dloader.main=your.alternative.class.path org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

As I understood, the Spring-boot's `org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher` class serves as a dispatching entrance class, and the `-Dloader.main` parameter tells it what to run.

Reference: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/20404

Comment: What if your jar is executable. i.e. when you unzip the jar, all the classes are preceded by "/BOOT-INF/classes/"

Comment: it worked for me. You can arguments as key/value pair at the end of above command

Comment: @Zhou, you are a life-saver. Thank you.

Comment: Using Spring Boot, exactly what I was looking for - thanks so much!

Comment: Looks like `PropertiesLauncher` has been moved into a **launch** package. The right package is now `org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.PropertiesLauncher`.

Answer (score 24):

Apart from calling `java -jar myjar.jar com.mycompany.Myclass`, you can also make the main class in your Manifest a Dispatcher class.

**Example:**

```
public class Dispatcher{

    private static final Map<String, Class<?>> ENTRY_POINTS =
        new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
    static{
        ENTRY_POINTS.put("foo", Foo.class);
        ENTRY_POINTS.put("bar", Bar.class);
        ENTRY_POINTS.put("baz", Baz.class);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception{

        if(args.length < 1){
            // throw exception, not enough args
        }
        final Class<?> entryPoint = ENTRY_POINTS.get(args[0]);
        if(entryPoint==null){
            // throw exception, entry point doesn't exist
        }
        final String[] argsCopy =
            args.length > 1
                ? Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 1, args.length)
                : new String[0];
        entryPoint.getMethod("main", String[].class).invoke(null,
            (Object) argsCopy);

    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good alternative way to do it! My jar was created using "spring-boot:repackage", so I just can't run other entrance classes by the "-cp" way. I don't know what the spring-boot plugin did to the jar. In this case, a dispatching class helps.

Answer (score 3):

Another similar option that I think Nick briefly alluded to in the comments is to create multiple wrapper jars. I haven't tried it, but I think they could be completely empty other than the manifest file, which should specify the main class to load as well as the inclusion of the MyJar.jar to the classpath.

MyJar**1**.jar\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.mycomp.myproj.dir1.MainClass1
Class-Path: MyJar.jar
```

MyJar**2**.jar\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.mycomp.myproj.dir2.MainClass2
Class-Path: MyJar.jar
```

etc.
Then just run it with `java -jar MyJar2.jar`

Answer (score 1):

First of all `jar` creates a jar, and does not run it. Try `java -jar` instead.

Second, why do you pass the class twice, as FQCN (`com.mycomp.myproj.dir2.MainClass2`) and as file (`com/mycomp/myproj/dir2/MainClass2.class`)?

Edit:

It seems as if `java -jar` requires a main class to be specified. You could try `java -cp your.jar com.mycomp.myproj.dir2.MainClass2 ...` instead. `-cp` sets the jar on the classpath and enables java to look up the main class there.

Comment: I did as mentioned here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: From that page: "It can be used while creating or updating a jar file." - So this is used to set the main class attribute, not to run the jar.