# How to run Java .jar without MANIFEST.MF?

Tags: java, manifest

Is it possible to run a Java app which doesn't contain `MANIFEST.MF` file? Of course, there's static `main` method,just lacks manifest file. And the app is depending on several external `.jar` files.

If is this possible, how to do that?

Answer (score 30):

It is possible, you can specify the class to run from the command line:

```
java -cp yourJar.jar your.main.Class
```

Same question here:

[How to run a class from Jar which is not the Main-Class in its Manifest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474666/how-to-run-a-class-from-jar-which-is-not-the-main-class-in-its-manifest-file)

Comment: It's strange that the above works but `java -jar your.main.Class` does not.

Comment: @backslash, by running above code if getting Error like : "Could not find or load main class"
What to debug ?

Comment: @IshitaShah It means that the class could not be found or is not a main class. Did you check the class name and the package name? Are you 100% sure your class has a correct main method definition?

Comment: My class does not has main method, But I have include one of the plugin and after that I execute and got this error.

Comment: @IshitaShah The class you run ***must*** have a main method. It's the first method run by the JVM, if you don't have that your app won't run. That's why you get that error.

Comment: @BackSlash, That is the Problem only. I am having project with TestNG,  where java main method is override by Test annotation. So there is no main method.

Comment: @IshitaShah TestNG has a completely different way of running tests, you need to go through their documentation to learn how to run tests from command line. I'm not familiar with TestNG, so I can't help.

Answer (score 12):

You can also add the manifest, with the following command:

```
jar  -uvfe  your.jar foo.bar.Baz
java -jar your.jar        # tries to run main in foo.bar.Baz
```

Answer (score 3):

Of course! Just use this:

```
java -cp MyJar.jar com.example.Main
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes , use this

java -cp myJar.jar package.className