# Java project with only build.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have prior experience with working with Struts and Spring MVC frameworks and java applications.
At work I received a Java project code which runs as a service on a Linux server, picks files from the server and through axis2 web service it returns some response.

In the config files I see only `build.xml` in the project.
I am a bit confused as what kind of a Java project this is and how do I deploy this code on my local eclipse.

This would really help as I am the only Java resource on the floor and with 1.5 yrs of exp.
They expect me to know everything.

Comment: looks like an `ant` built project to me

Comment: You can try using File > New > Other, and then select "Java Project from existing Ant Build File" option (available under the Java Project)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I have been able to build the project now by clicking on build.xml -run as- ant build It has created a jar file. But when i deploy the jar file from command prompt it says could not find or load main class. What do I do next.

Comment: The "could not find or load main class" error usually means you have an invalid command line. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15626369/how-to-run-java-jar-without-manifest-mf) for some tips.