# How to run main class packed in springboot jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, program-entry-point

My project uses springboot, after pack it to jar file, I can execute `java -jar my-project.jar` to run the instance.

I also have a script which is a main class, when I execute `java -cp my-project.jar com.test.MyScript`, it says `Could not find or load main class`.

How can this happen? By the way, when I execute `java -cp my-project.jar com.test.MyApplication`, the same error occurs. `MyApplication` is the `SpringBootApplication` class.

Why can't I manually run the main class?

Comment: Correct alternative can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61601687/3805988

Answer (score 1):

That is because spring boot doesn't use the `SpringBootApplication` as the main entry point. It uses `org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher`.

Excerpt from the [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html):

> The org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher class is a special
>   bootstrap class that is used as an executable jar’s main entry point.
>   It is the actual Main-Class in your jar file, and it is used to setup
>   an appropriate URLClassLoader and ultimately call your main() method.

Comment: may I add my script main class as the param of `Launcher` to run my script?

Comment: May be this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976514/multiple-runnable-classes-inside-jar-how-to-run-them

Comment: Try this, worked for me
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/61601687/3805988