# Run main of specific class inside a package subdirectory

Tags: java

I am following [Scheduled Jobs with Custom Clock Processes in Java with Quartz and RabbitMQ](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes-java-quartz-rabbitmq) but I struggle to actually run another dyno from withing the jar file packeg by Spring.

In the package (`server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`) I need to run the `company.server.Scheduler`. The `.class` file is in `BOOT-INF/classes`.

I've tried to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32439530/826983) but I am always getting

```
Error: Could not find or load main class company.server.Scheduler
```

I'm struggling to get the syntax right.

So what I need to run is

```
BOOT-INF/classes/company/server/Scheduler.class
```

I have tried this:

```
java -classpath BOOT-INF/classes -jar server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar company.server.Scheduler
java -classpath server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/BOOT-INF/classes company.server.Scheduler
```

But this either runs the main class from the Manifest or crashes.

Also tried:

```
java -classpath server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar BOOT-INF.classes.company.server.Scheduler
java -classpath server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar BOOT-INF/classes/company/server/Scheduler
```

---

### Try it out ...

```
git clone https://github.com/silentsnooc/run-scheduler
cd run-scheduler/
mvn clean install
cd target/
java -cp .:scheduler-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar BOOT-INF.classes.Scheduler
```

If I follow [this on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes-java-quartz-rabbitmq#running-on-heroku) then it should be something like

```
java -cp scheduler-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:BOOT-INF/classes/* Scheduler
```

but it's not working telling me the main class Scheduler could not be found.

Comment: is `BOOT-INF/classes` a folder **inside** the jar?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Yes. This jar file gets packaged by Spring which is moving all the compiled stuff into `BOOT-INF/classes` afaik.

Comment: then try `java -classpath server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar BOOT-INF.classes.company.server.Scheduler`

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Just tried it. It does not work unfortunately. Could it be because `BOOT-INF` is not a vaild package name?

Comment: do you get the same error message still?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Yes. That produces `Could not find or load main class ...` again.

Comment: Is there a `Scheduler.class` file?

Comment: @SamOrozco Yes, I checked. The file is there.

Comment: Try adding `-cp .` to your java call. That will add the current dir to the classpath.

Comment: @SamOrozco Still nothing :/

Comment: Ok, now show your current java call.

Comment: Is `BOOT-INF/classes` part of the manifests *ClassPath* entry?

Comment: @SamOrozco I'm currently at `java -cp . -classpath server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar BOOT-INF.classes.company.server.Scheduler`

Comment: Try this: `java -cp .:server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar BOOT-INF.classes.company.server.Scheduler` or  this `java -cp ".:server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" BOOT-INF.classes.company.server.Scheduler`

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I can't see a ClassPath entry in the manifest file. All I see is `Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher` and a few other things. The only mention of that directory is in `Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/`.

Comment: @SamOrozco Still no luck :/

Comment: I suggest a *delegation* class in the regular package structure.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Now sure how to do that? In the meantime I created a little github repo which should generate a simple jar. (https://github.com/silentsnooc/run-scheduler)