# Received error when copying example code to eclipse JAVA

Tags: java, class

```
class Animal {
    public void animalSound() {
    System.out.println("The animal makes a sound");
  }
}

class Pig extends Animal {
  public void animalSound() {
    System.out.println("The pig says: wee wee");
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  public void animalSound() {
    System.out.println("The dog says: bow wow");
  }
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal myAnimal = new Animal();
    Animal myPig = new Pig();
    Animal myDog = new Dog();
        
    myAnimal.animalSound();
    myPig.animalSound();
    myDog.animalSound();
  }
}
```

So I copied and pasted this piece of code from w3schools. I named the file polymorphism.java, but when i run it on command prompt, it gives me this error: can't find main(String[]) method in class: Animal
What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

From error message we see that java is looking for method `main(String[])` in class `Animal`. Now if we look into code you pasted we can see that indeed Animal class doesn't have this method. Class `Main` has this method. You need to specify to look for `main` method in `Main` class instead of `Animal` class.

Comment: And umm how do I do that Lol. Sorry I'm new to this stuff.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32439530/10741530 this answer will resolve your problem.

Comment: Um I just moved the class Main to the top and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

you should provide the @Override annotation after overriding the methods.
Works for me:

```
class Animal1 {
    public void animalSound() {
    System.out.println("The animal makes a sound");
  }
}

class Pig extends Animal1 {
    
  @Override 
  public void animalSound() {
    System.out.println("The pig says: wee wee");
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal1 {
  @Override
  public void animalSound() {
    System.out.println("The dog says: bow wow");
  }
}

class Main extends Dog {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

      Animal1 d = new Animal1();
      d.animalSound();
      Animal1 myPig = new Pig();
        Animal1 myDog = new Dog();
            
        d.animalSound();
        myPig.animalSound();
        myDog.animalSound();
  }
}
```