# centralize logs from different instances of a java application

Tags: java, logging, logback, slf4j

I have a need to centralize the 2 logs file of my application deployed in 2 different server in prod environment.

If possible I would like to use logback and not logstash cause we already support it in the java app.

I did some research but I found lot of solutions for generate more log files but not to unite the ones I already have.

What I would like to achieve is **the merge of this 2 logs file either into a new log file or in a database** because then I need to send the union of this 2 logs  through a REST Service.

Could you help me?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe use a service that does it for you like Elastic Search with Kibana, or DataDog...

Comment: Another option is to use the same log on both servers using Network Log or it might be called Socket Log.   In LogBack that is called ServerSocketAppender: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#serverSocketAppender

Comment: Regarding the serverSocketAppender I'm trying to understand how it works. In the doc is written: "start SimpleSocketServer with the following command:
java ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SimpleSocketServer 6000 \
  src/main/java/chapters/appenders/socket/server1.xml"
If I run it I get: "Error: Could not find or load main class ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SimpleSocketServer" I don't understand the command...

Comment: ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SimpleSocketServer what should it be ? a URL ? or should I download the logback repository and find that class? cause it's seem to me that my bash can't find it

Comment: About the class not found, it means you need to set the classpath like this: java -cp LOGBACK.jar  ch.qos.logback.classic.net.Simple...     just need to know what the path+filename of the logback jar.   See here how to run java with classpath in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474666/how-to-run-a-class-from-jar-which-is-not-the-main-class-in-its-manifest-file

Comment: Another option - but not sure it fits all cases...  is the write a small service that its function is only to write logs.   and any server that wants to write a log simply calls this "microservice" using REST.